# cloudkit - I do not want the images with my table to download

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have a table that has 3 text fields and an image(CKAsset). The images are large. I want to query the table and only receive the 2 text fields without downloading the image also. Is there a way to specify that I only want the 2 text fields?

This is the code I'm using:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "CloudID = %@", tempCloudID)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Images", predicate: predicate)
    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Field1", ascending: true)]
    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Field2", ascending: true)]
```

Still cannot query the tables, they are store properly though with the reference, and are deleted when I delete the owning table.

```
func test() {
    //This works for storing my images, and I can delete the parent and it successfully removes all images. That’s what I want.
    let parentId = CKRecordID(recordName: uploadList[uploadRecord].CloudID)
    let parent = CKReference(recordID: parentId, action: CKReferenceAction.DeleteSelf)
    let outputPath = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/Library/Pictures/" + uploadList[uploadRecord].File)
    let File: CKAsset? = CKAsset(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath))
    let imageRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Images")
    imageRecord.setObject(uploadList[uploadRecord].R, forKey: "R")
    imageRecord.setObject(uploadList[uploadRecord].A, forKey: "A")
    imageRecord.setObject(parent, forKey: "Reference")
    imageRecord.setValue(File, forKey: "Image")
    publicDB.saveRecord(imageRecord, completionHandler: ({returnRecord, error in
        if let err = error {
            self.notifyUser("Save Image Error", message:
                err.localizedDescription)
            print("Image Upload Error")
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                print("Image Sent Successfully")
                // Mark image to be deleted?
            }
        }
    }))

}
```

I have tried querying through addoperation and perform query. I am doing something wrong, not sure what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve this in 2 ways:

1. You could use a CKQueryOperation where you can specify the desiredKeys. You then would have to query / get the same record with the key for the asset if you do want the asset. You could do that with fetchRecordWithID. The disadvantage of that is that it would get the entire record again. If a record contains 2 asset, you can't specify to get only one.
2. You could put your CKAssets in a separate asset recordType and set a CKReference to it. You can then selectively only get that specific asset record.

P.S. Querying a reference like asked below can be done with code like:

```
 let parentId = CKRecordID(recordName: referenceRecordName)
 let parent = CKReference(recordID: parentId, action: CKReferenceAction.None)
 let query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", referenceField ,parent))
```

Comment: I only have 2 tables right now, I have not set them up using the CKReference right now,I am setting the 'CloudID' in the second table to be the ID from the first table. I looked at the CKReference but don't understand the documentation to get it working and can't find a good example. I don't want to add another table without using the proper CKReference as I will have to keep track of another 'ID'. The next step after I do this is to get the images, right now I just need the list of images for them to pick from. I will try the CKQueryOperation. I should really add a zoneID and CKReferences.

Comment: I still cannot find a way to set the CKReference on this table. The tempCloudID =13886D9B-8389-4253-981D-51DCD573BA05 and that should be the owner. How would I set the Images table to have a reference to that ID?

Comment: I fixed the previous error using the CKQueryOperation. Now I have an error on the next screen where I try to open the image. I am using let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordID = %@", myRecordID). myRecordID = 3F1CF4EC-95F4-4659-AA47-B00048B3BBAE. The error is: Field '__recordID' has a value type of reference and cannot be queried by using filter value type string.

Comment: You should query with a CKReference and not a string. See the updated awnser

Comment: I am trying to save data to another table with a reference. I am getting the error from the above code on the let query = line. The error is: use of unresolved identifier referenceField. The referenceRecordName is set to the 'owner table' and is a string, and the recordType has been changed to my table. I don't think I have to do anything to the 'owner' table?

Comment: referenceField is a placeholder for the field where the reference is in. You could create a variable for it like: let referenceField = "myFieldname" or you could just replace it with the string "myFieldname"

Comment: Onto the next problem, I think they are called batch updates?